# javascript window.open() Character encoding changes

Tags: extjs

I used extjs 3.4 and I used alfresco 4.2
 I have problem in the name of some file which are downloaded from alfresco.

using this code I try to download  the file :

```
var url = panel.uploaderurl;
                url += "?cmd=download";
                url += "&id=" + rec.get('ATTACHMENT_ID');
                url += "&docid=" +  rec.get('DOCID');
                url += "&file=" +  rec.get('DOCNAME');              
                url += "&uploader=" + panel.uploader;
                url += "&type=" + panel.type;           
                window.open(url);
```

debugging the code I found that the URL contain :

**/test?cmd=download&id=ATT-189208&docid=1829db8d-8291-4429-b11a-7bfdac340f42&file=توصيف المقرر علم وظائف الأعضاء.doc&uploader=com.testUpload&type=CO**

but When the file is downloaded into the disc it has this name :

**-H5JA 'DEB11 9DE H8'&A 'D#96'! .doc**

so **توصيف المقرر علم وظائف الأعضاء.doc** became  **-H5JA 'DEB11 9DE H8'&A 'D#96'! .doc**

I try without success to change this line :

```
window.open(url);
```

with

```
window.open(unescape(decodeURIComponent( url )));
```

**updated** :

the file is correctly downloaded to the disc and only the name is wrong

I try without success with code :

```
window.open(url, "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=800, height=900, top=10, left=10");
```

I used chrome as a navigator

Comment: If the file is correctly downloaded to the disc, and only the name is wrong, it looks like an issue with the browser or the web server. What happens if you download the file manually?

Comment: thank you for your response, but I have the same problem when I try to modify the code ,

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? If it even happens when you download the file manually, it is either a browser or web server problem. If it happens in a single browser, file a bug report with that browser's vendor. If it happens with every browser, file a bug report with the web server vendor.